# R "Pool" support vector machines for subsetting data sets

Tags: r, svm

Facts for svm:

positve data set 20 samples, 5 factors
negative data set 10000 samples, 5 factors
package: e1071 or kernel
My test dataset would be something like 15000 samples

To control this imbalance i tried to use the class weight in e1071, as suggested in previous questions.But i cannot see any differences also whole overweighting one class extremely. 
Now i was thinking to subset my negative data set randomly in 100 sub negative datasets. Like this

```
cost<-vector("numeric", length(1))
gamma <- vector("numeric", length(1))
    accuracy<- vector("numeric" , length(1)
```

)

### Function definition

```
split_data<- function(x,repeats) {
    for (i in 1:repeats){
        random_data <- x[sample(1:nrow(x), 100),]
        dat<- rbind(data_pos, random_data)
        svm <- svm(Class~., data=dat, cross=10)
        cost[i] <- svm$cost
        gamma[i] <-svm$gamma
        accuracy[i]<- svm$tot.accuracy
        print(summary(svm))
}
  return(matrix(c(cost,gamma,accuracy), ncol=3))
}
```

But Im not sure what to do now with ... :D Its seems to define always the same support vectors in my pos data set. But there should be a smarter strategy, i have read about some strategies but is it possible to realize them in R with any package?

Edit:

I would like to find an approach how i can deal with highly imbalanced datasets.And i would like to do it in this way: to split my negative data set (resampled test data set) in equal portions to my positive dataset. However I would then somehow like to get the complete accuracy and sensitivity.
My question in particular is: how can i manage this in R a nice way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Can you expand on your text to explain the problem more?

Comment: Two things (1) From your code I see that you are not tuning the SVM parameters, is that intentional? (2) Behavior of SVM (and most other machine learning methods) depends on the data. So when you say, you don't see any difference when you overweight one class (I guess the minority) might be due to how the data looks like. For starters you can plot the data in 2 dimensions using PCA.